# Why Does the indexPathsForSelectedRows fail when I use reloadData and how can I fix it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method I have the following section of code:

```
     if ([tableView isEqual:cheeseTableView]) {

    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {



        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;




    } else {


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



    }

    NSLog(@"Called didSelecRowAtIndexPath: cheeseTableView");

    self.cheeseIndexPath = [self.cheeseTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

}
```

The table has the following capabilities: `cheeseTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;`

At the end of the method I have the following line: `[tableView reloadData];`

When I use the code as it stands the `[self.cheeseIndexPath count]` always returns one.  But when I remove the `reloadData` method I get the proper count but nothing displays as it should.  How can I get it to display properly and get the correct count?

Comment: You should not be changing the cell in didSelectRow, you should be identifying that cell in your dataSource.  Then, when reloadData is called, cellForRow should examine the dataSource and properly modify the cell.  General rule:  Never modify a cell except in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to turn the checkmark on/off depending on selection, then using the cell itself is not a good approach if you are using cell reuse. You need to store the on/off values in an array that has the same number of rows as your data, then in the didSelectRow you need to toggle the value. In the cellForRow, use this array to set the checkmark appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few questions that may guide you in the right direction.

1) Why do you need to reload the data of your tableView? IMO, there's nothing in the code you are showing that is worth reloading data.

2) What is the array self.cheeseIndexPath is supposed to hold?

If you wish to hold the indexPath of all the cells that have been checked, I would add/remove the indexPath right in the selection code:

```
NSTableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        // remove the indexPath from the array
        [self.cheeseIndexPath removeObject:indexPath];
        // change anything of the cell that was just selected
        currentCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor newColor];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        // add the indexPath from the array
        [self.cheeseIndexPath addObject:indexPath];
        // change anything of the cell that was just selected
        currentCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor newColor];
    }
```

3) `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` will not return all the cells with `cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` in your tableView.

Also, it might be worth to mention that all the cells that are not visible should be considered nil (because of the dequeueing mechanism).

Hope this helps...

---

**EDIT**
In the code snippet, I added comments and code for handling changing background color of the cell (to answer @SonOfSeuss comment, not the OP).

Comment: Your solutions implementation doesn't work.  The `reload` makes the dark background turn white after choosing the cells.  Also in your solution nothing saves whether I leave the `reload` out or not.

Comment: Everything works if I take the `reload` out.  Otherwise nothing works.

Comment: Like I said, there's nothing in the code you showed us that justifies the `reloadData`, so yes I would remove it. But it could serve a purpose we don't see. For the rest of the code, I wrote it directly in the answer box, so please forgive any typo I could have made. I used that logic numerous time, though, so the logic should work.

Comment: Oh, and very important: I assumed that you would change self.cheeseIndexPath from an NSArray to an NSMutableArray. Apply that change in the property declaration and when you initialize it.

Comment: Taking `reload` out is simply hiding the basic design flaw.

Comment: There is no `NSTableViewCell` but `UITableViewCell`.  Also there is no `cellAtIndexPath:`, it's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  It's also not working.

Comment: @SonOfSeuss - Well, I told you what you need to do.  It's up to you to do it.

Comment: @HotLicks you did.  I take your advice onboard.  It was a fundamental design flaw.  Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. In my case it worked in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
NSMutableArray * checkedCells = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (UIView *view in tableView.subviews) {
            for (ProductAddonTableViewCell *cell in view.subviews) {
                if (cello.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)                {      
                    [checkedCells addObject:cell];
                }
            }
    }
```